# How to join/combine/merge two oracle sql queries

Tags: plsqldeveloper

Could you please help out me on this issue.

I have two queries , we have to join/combine/merge one query to other. The results would be from query 1 only. these two queries have with clause.

Thanks For Your Help!!
Ravindra

Comment: Can you give an simplistic example - why do you want to combine two queries, if the results are always only from query 1? Maybe it is a join with a surrounding select with a where clause.  Do you want to combine columns, then a `join` might be right; If you want to combine rows into the same column `union`.